# Rails simple_form not pushing data field to database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Ok so I'm trying to use simple form to create a course. The form does not push the data to the database. I have it working using the Select_tag from Rails but cannot get data validation working this way. I'm now trying to update the select_tag to work with simple_form. Data validation is working but the form tag f.association is not recognising the data.

The category model relation is correct to Course as I've gotten it working with the code below.

```
<%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Select Category") %>
```

This is the simple form code that does let me select through the available categories but it doesn't push the id to the database.I'll add my controller / model below for sanity checks. Thanks.

Course Model

```
         validates :course_reference, :title, :course_img_file_name, :description, :short_description, :venue, :duration_days, :duration_weeks, :start_date, :start_time, :end_date, :max_enrolment, :price, :category_id, :presence => true

searchkick

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :location
```

Category Model

`class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses
end`

Course Controller

```
def new
    @course = current_user.courses.build
    @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}
    @locations = Location.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}
end

def create
    @course = current_user.courses.build(course_params)
    @course.category_id = params[:category_id]
    @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}
    @locations = Location.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}

    if @course.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Any help as always is appreciated. Thanks.

Just to add whats going on in the background when creating a course when i remove presence = true for category_id

`Started POST "/courses" for ::1 at 2017-05-22 15:54:13 +0100
Processing by CoursesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"du0IPedCSPueWp1RIOqWNenXiIpQLMLSohvt1ls7BUteoDFxzGFpVQ959iryIq+wBEUeaNOkAmA3jCjAG+d0Vw==", "course"=>{"course_reference"=>"cf0002", "course_img"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fce9a6ee950 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/gx/86yj74bx3md88cfn2fwc975h0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170522-1878-15pqchz.png>, @original_filename="Health Course Red.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"course[course_img]\"; filename=\"Health Course Red.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "title"=>"Infection Control 1022", "category_id"=>"1", "description"=>"test", "short_description"=>"Short description should really be kept to the snappy bare bones", "venue"=>"36 annamoe park, cabra, dublin", "duration_days"=>"1", "duration_weeks"=>"1", "start_date(1i)"=>"2017", "start_date(2i)"=>"5", "start_date(3i)"=>"22", "start_time(1i)"=>"2017", "start_time(2i)"=>"5", "start_time(3i)"=>"22", "start_time(4i)"=>"14", "start_time(5i)"=>"48", "end_date(1i)"=>"2017", "end_date(2i)"=>"5", "end_date(3i)"=>"22", "max_enrolment"=>"1", "price"=>"1"}, "_wysihtml5_mode"=>"1", "location_id"=>"", "commit"=>"Create Course"}`

Category ID is there in the parameter. But if I look at the SQL query it is not included.

```
SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "courses" ("title", "description", "price", "course_img_file_name", "course_img_content_type", "course_img_file_size", "course_img_updated_at", "venue", "max_enrolment", "course_reference", "short_description", "duration_days", "duration_weeks", "start_date", "start_time", "end_date", "user_id", "latitude", "longitude", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["title", "Infection Control 1022"], ["description", "test"], ["price", 1], ["course_img_file_name", "Health_Course_Red.png"], ["course_img_content_type", "image/png"], ["course_img_file_size", 17181], ["course_img_updated_at", "2017-05-22 14:54:13.012445"], ["venue", "36 annamoe park, cabra, dublin"], ["max_enrolment", 1], ["course_reference", "cf0002"], ["short_description", "Short description should really be kept to the snappy bare bones"], ["duration_days", 1.0], ["duration_weeks", 1.0], ["start_date", "2017-05-22"], ["start_time", "2017-05-22 14:48:00.000000"], ["end_date", "2017-05-22"], ["user_id", 1], ["latitude", 53.3598805], ["longitude", -6.289487299999999], ["created_at", "2017-05-22 14:54:13.705340"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-22 14:54:13.705340"]]
```

(2.7ms)  commit transaction
  Course Store (27.7ms)  {"id":3}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/

Course Params looks ok as it has :category_id

`def course_params
            params.require(:course).permit(:title, :description, :price, :category_id, :course_img, :venue, :location_id, :max_enrolment, :course_reference, :short_description, :duration_days, :duration_weeks, :start_date, :start_time, :end_date, :user_id, :complete)
        end`

Comment: Can you pasted the `course_params` definition?

Comment: Hi @JCorcuera, Have added it there. The course creation works fine when I use the select tag function from Rails. It's when I try to use simple_forms way it fails. The strong params are above now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
@course = current_user.courses.build(course_params)
@course.category_id = params[:category_id]
```

For what i see the `category_id` is inside `course_params`, so when you build the object is there but later you assign it to `params[:category_id]` which is `nil`.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this so. Will come back to you once I've tested this out. Thanks a mil. I've a similar issue i've just posted up right now and I've tried that thinking it may be something similar however it hadn't worked. Thanks dude.

Comment: Yep that was it alright. Legend. Thanks @JCorcuera. Can't believe I wrecked my head for hours and it was as simple as that. I was under the impression I had to call the parameter because it wasn't from the same model and was an association. It definitely make sense that because I mentioned it in the strong params it was bringing it in from the form already. Thanks again man. Marked it as correct.